# How to resolve issue using MailApp.sendEmail with iPhone and iPad?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-sheets, google-forms

I have created a Google form for participating in an Event by Blogger. This form sends an automatic reply email to the `Email` address registered by an applicant from the spreadsheet for confirmation of the application.
 This blog is still a trial version. So I have unlisted readers in Blogger.
I'm testing the form using a couple of different devices, iPhone and iPad. 
 There is a problem. It is to come out a phenomenon that is not able to receive Email that should have been sent by `MailApp.sendEmail`.
I'm stumped. There are two situations.

1st

### Using an iPhone to browse the blog and apply for participating in an Event.

If the applicant registered the Email address that is used only in another Windows device,and that is not used in this iPhone, does not have received an automatic reply e-mail on the mailer of Windows device.
But I was sure that the remaining transmission record in the Sent Mail folder of Gmail.

2nd

### Use an ipad to browse the blog and apply to participating in an Event.

If the applicant registered the Email address that is used only in another Andoroid device,and that is not used in iPad,does not have received an automatic reply e-mail on the mailer of Andoroid device.
In this pattern, the Email is not recorded in the Sent Mail folder of Gmail, and is also Not sent.

I don't know whether the problem is specific to GAS or Gmail?
How do I resolve this?

The following is the code.

```
function sendMailForm() {
    Logger.log('sendMailForm() debug start');
    var subject = "test"; 
    var body
        = "Japanese Message \n"
        +"Japanese Message\n"
        + "------------------------------------------------------------\n";

    var footer
        = "------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
        +"Japanese Message\n\n"
        +"------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
        + "------------------------------------------------------------";
    var NAME_COL_NAME = ''Japanese ColName;
    var MAIL_COL_NAME = 'Japanese ColName';
    var TIME_COL_NAME = 'Japanese ColName';
    var EXCLUDE_COLS = ['Japanese ColName','Japanese ColName'];
    var EXCLUDE_COLS_VALUE ="";
    var admin = "Myadress@mydomain";
    var spread_sheet_id = 'MyspreadID';

    try{
        var ss   = SpreadsheetApp. openById(spread_sheet_id);
        var sh   = ss.getActiveSheet();
        var rows = sh.getLastRow();
        var cols = sh.getLastColumn();
        var rg   = sh.getDataRange();
        Logger.log("rows="+rows+" cols="+cols);
        var to = ""; 
        for ( var j = 1; j <= cols; j++ ) {
            var col_name  = rg.getCell(1, j).getValue(); 
            var col_value = rg.getCell(rows, j).getValue();

            if ( col_name === NAME_COL_NAME ) {
                body = col_value+" Japanese Message\n\n"+body;
            }
            if ( col_name === MAIL_COL_NAME ) {
                to = col_value;
            }
           if ( col_name == TIME_COL_NAME ) {
                col_name ="Japanese Message";
            }
           if ( EXCLUDE_COLS.length > 0 ) {
               is_exclude = false;
                for ( var k = 0; k < EXCLUDE_COLS.length; k++ ) {
                    if ( col_name === EXCLUDE_COLS[k] ) {
                        is_exclude = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
            if ( is_exclude ) {
                   continue;
            }
        }
        if(col_value == EXCLUDE_COLS_VALUE ){
                   continue;
        }

        body += col_name+"：";
        body += col_value + "\n\n";
      }
      body += footer;

      var options = {};
      if ( admin ) options.replyTo = admin;

      if ( to ) {
        MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body, options);
      }else{
        MailApp.sendEmail(admin, "JapaneseMessege", body);
      }
      var options = {};
      if ( to ) options.replyTo = to;
      Utilities.sleep(3000);
      MailApp.sendEmail(admin, subject, body, options);

    }catch(e){
       MailApp.sendEmail(admin, "Japanese Message", e.message);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Today, I tried to test again in the same situation,though I did not edit the Script code. I got the different results .

In the first situation, It was able to successfully receive automatic reply mail.
In the second situation, the Sent Email  recorded in the Sent Mail folder of Gmail,but the error message was returned from the mail server of Andoroid device of the destination. 

I think this results are normal.